# Can YouTrack baseurl be changed on Windows

Tags: windows, youtrack

I've installed YouTrack on Windows and by default the base url for it is `http://localhost`. Now I tried stoping service and changing it in `install_dir/conf/server.xml`, but it had no affect what so ever. Could it be done at all?

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this navigate to Administration-> Settings-> Base URL section or provide your base URL explicitly running YouTrack with java parameter

```
jetbrains.youtrack.baseUrl
```

Take a look at this [guide](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD5/YouTrack+Start+Java+Parameters), it may help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, well. It has no affect.

Comment: Provide me with the detailed steps of how did you try to complete this.